# How to get stroke parameters for bpy.ops.brush_stroke?

Tags: python, scripting, sculpting

Let's say I want to create an addon that creates my own brush stroke action in sculpt mode for Blender, but I can modify the stroke with python. Here's the smallest example of what I mean:

```
import bpy

class CustomSculpt(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "sculpt.my_stroke"
    bl_label = "Custom Stroke"

   
    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.sculpt.brush_stroke()

        return {'FINISHED'}
    
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(CustomSculpt)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(CustomSculpt)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Let's say I just want this to recreate the normal action of making a brush stroke while sculpting. It looks like I need the correct `stroke` parameter for `brush_stroke`. I assume this is data I could get from `context`? How would I find the correct values to fill the `stroke` parameter?

Related:

https://blenderartists.org/t/how-do-i-pass-coordinates-to-the-sculpt-brush-operator/597335/3

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.sculpt.html#bpy.ops.sculpt.brush_stroke

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.OperatorStrokeElement.html